# How to have a string hasher with preinitialized state just from std:: in Rust?

Tags: rust

Is it possible to have a hasher which does not use random initial state without having to import any crates? I'm browsing the docs but I'm not finding a solution. It seems like the only option involves `RandomState`

This does not have to be any fancy hasher. I'll even to uniqeness check afterwards to make sure I don't have collisions.

Comment: [`std::collections::hash_map::DefaultHasher::new()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.54.0/std/collections/hash_map/struct.DefaultHasher.html#method.new)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`BuildHasherDefault`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.54.0/std/hash/struct.BuildHasherDefault.html). It constructs a [`Hasher`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.54.0/std/hash/trait.Hasher.html) using its `Default` implementation.

For example,

```rust
use std::collections::hash_map::DefaultHasher;
use std::hash::BuildHasherDefault;

type DefaultedHashMap<K, V> = HashMap<K, V, BuildHasherDefault<DefaultHasher>>;

let map = DefaultedHashMap::default();
```

Or:

```rust
use std::collections::hash_map::DefaultHasher;
use std::hash::BuildHasherDefault;

let map = HashMap::with_hasher(BuildHasherDefault::<DefaultHasher>::default());
```